# Use compiled .mexw64 function without matlab

Tags: python, c++, matlab, mex, scilab

This may be due to my inexpertise in the area, but I'm looking for a way to use a function already compiled in a .mexw64 in a language or program different than MATLAB.

So far, I've found plenty of ways to create a code in other languages to compile into a .mexw64  for a further use in MATLAB, but here what I want to do is to use a fully compiled .mexw64 function (given by someone else) in, lets say, scilab (or any other language for the matter).

I have no interest in looking at the code (although it is definitely a plus), I only want to use it as a black box where I input what it needs and I get the normal output of it. Any solution that allows me to do this in another program or language other than MATLAB is welcomed. I don't know if this is possible or if it is a lost cause.

Comment: Mex functions are dll files. I never tried it, but there are multiple tools to get informations about an "unknown" dll file, maybe you get something useful out of it.

Comment: Never seen it done before, but maybe Octave provides something like that [MEX-files in octave](
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Mex_002dFiles.html) . Would be interested if you succeed

Comment: To use mex files you need matlab runtime libraries. You are much better off bypassing the mex layer, extract the underlying C functions of the business logic.

Comment: Octave is only source code compatible, not binary compatible. That would at least be a possible work around, you may get in touch with the author and ask him to mex the file again using octave.

Comment: @user3528438: [Matlab Runtime](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) is the wrong word. It would be available free of charge and it is what dlls and other native code deployed with the Matlab Compiler use to run without Matlab. A final answer to that is what I expected from further analysing the dll, does it use only libraries available via Matlab Runtime or also parts which are only available in Matlab.

Comment: @Daniel By matlab runtime libraries I mean libraries that supports the mex api calls in the mex layer.

Comment: What you need is probably Matlab engine api http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html which lets you call matlab routines in c/c++

Comment: The critical part is the mex library API, not the engine. The engine is for external applications.  http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mex-library.html